# Why does my MacBook air have so many MAC addresses, according to my router?

Tags: network, macos, mac-address, mac-spoofing

I am investigating some strange issues with my home network, and decided to have a look at my device history.

I only have one Macbook Air, but my device history is showing ten, all with different MAC addresses (as well as a variation in the name). The first one in the list is the correct one:

[image: Odd device history, showing lots of MacBook air's]

I see it's possible to randomise MAC addresses on macOS, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't happen natively, and I haven't done anything to change this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/282605/18070

This question was prompted by my printer randomly printing this:

[image: Printout showing HTTP requests against my printer]

After some Googling, I figured out that any HTTP request against port 9100 on my printer prompts it to print out details of the request.

The firewall is on, on the router, that port isn't accessible from my public IP address, so I figure somebody would need to be on my network to do it.

No device on my network has this particular version of curl.

Should I be worried, or is this some sort of 'feature' of macOS I'm not aware off?

Thanks

Comment: Ah no worries, so they ransomized the name as well? Feel free to add an answer if you learn more and I'll mark it as the answer, thanks

Comment: By any chance, are you using a Netgear Orbi mesh system, or are you running Netgear Armour security scans?

Comment: I have Netgear Armour on my router @mti2935, yes

Answer (score 1):

After a little research as a result of your additional information prodding.

I don't think this is MAC randomization on your Mac Air.

I believe this is someone else attempting, **and failing**, to break into your network.

Double-check all your security settings just to be sure.

Your known MAC shows a connection type of "*Wireless*", all of the others show as "*Unknown*", indicating they did not successfully authenticate and get an IP address on your network.

The Printer stuff suggests that your Printer is WiFi capable and may not be secured properly. If so, the printer could *potentially* become an access point into your network.

Comment: I think @mti2935 's answer about *Netgear-Armor* explains the printer.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that you are running Netgear Armor.

The spontaneous pages printed by your computer are probably a result of the security scan by Netgear Armor.  See https://community.netgear.com/t5/NETGEAR-Armor/Printer-spontaneously-prints-when-Netgear-Armor-Security-Scans/td-p/1824982

If you are running BitDefender on your Apple device, this (in combination with Netgear Armor) may be causing the Apple device to appear with multiple MAC addresses on your network.  See https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/27897/.

Comment: **I think your answer about Netgear-Armor explains the printer.** It seems unlikely that *BitDefender* would generate new but related device names while also failing to connect.

Comment: Thanks both, I'm not running BitDefender on my Macbook however @user10216038